# Clickable Image HTML

Tags: html

I have the following code for a background image:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
 <td style="background-image: url(SOMEIMAGE.png); 
  width: 305px; height: 23px;
   text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
     border: 0px #FFFFFF solid">
    <a href="SOMELINK.COM" style="color: white; text-decoration: none">THIS IS A TEST   LINK</a>
    </td></tr></table>
```

The text defined within the image is clickable, but the background image itself is not. 
Is it possible to make it so the background image and text is clickable to go to another link?

Comment: ... make it the background of the anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the anchor a block element

```
<a href="SOMELINK.COM" style="display:block; height: 100%; color: white; text-decoration: none">
```

**Or** you could make the background the background of the anchor instead of the td, and apply the sizes to it too.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <a href="SOMELINK.COM" style="color: white; text-decoration: none; background-image: url(SOMEIMAGE.png); 
                width: 305px; height: 23px;
                display:block;
                border: 0px #FFFFFF solid">THIS IS A TEST LINK</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That seems to work great! The only thing is that the text is appearing centered and on the top of the image... how can I center it and make it centered on the image?

Comment: you can use line-height for that

Answer (score 1):

Turn your link into a block level element:

```
a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wZLus/)**

This way it will take up the full width and height of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
 <td style="width: 305px; height: 23px;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
     border: 0px #FFFFFF solid">

    <a href="SOMELINK.COM" style="background-image:url(SOMEIMAGE.png);display:block;color: white;text-decoration: none">THIS IS A TEST   LINK</a>

</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

plus read this 
http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks06.htm

Comment: Could you make this answer in context of the code given?

Comment: sure give me a moment :)